# Шифрование данных - доступ к API соц-сетей

Tags: безопасность, wordpress-плагины

Пишу мини плагин для wordpress.

Возник вопрос, как правильно и безопасно хранить доступы (Токены, ключи, айди) к API соц сетей ?

Я хочу создать страницу плагина, в которой по идее нужно будет прописывать только данные доступа для работы с соц-сетями.

Т.е плагин по идее должен будет работать так.

1.В настройках плагина мы заполняем необходимые данные доступов к API соц сетей

- Facebook
- Vkontakte
- Twitter
- Odnoklassniki

Вот только вопрос как это безопасно сделать и возможно ли вобще ? в плане их хранения в базе ?

Как лучше это сделать вобще ?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и безопасный способ - хранить ключи прямо в коде(если это php плагин, конечно). В базе можно но уже не так безопасно + любой запрос плагина означает предварительный запрос в базу, что нагружает БД и увеличивает время запроса.

Comment: Запросы идут только при публикации поста не более. Так что тут дело не в нагрузке а именно в безопасной реализации, тогда если их хранить в коде, то создавать страницу администратирования плагина нет нужды

Comment: Именно. Главное создать инструкуцию по изменению константы и все. Альтернатива БД только хранение в коде. Можно хранит в файле но это еще более небезопасно, даже если это шифровать. С другой стороны, можно создать специальный php файл, определяющий константы ключей и в странице настроек этот файл генерировать, а в скрипте подключать. Очень прикольно получится, мне кажется.

Comment: Да, но как сделать так, чтобы было и удобно и безопасно ? ведь ключи - в некоторых соц-сетях не вечные, но это отдельная тема. В общем тут середины нет, просто хочется сделать все просто и красиво но и безопасно в том числе. Просто ваша реализация не из простых хотя имеет место быть. Но если получится сделать вычные ключи, тогда можно и вшить.

Comment: Страница с настройками гренерирующая php-файл. По мне так можно написать минут за 20, если без особых изысков) просто подставить в текстовый шаблон значения ключей и записать. Если вам сложно - могу помочь лично и безвозмездно

Comment: Мне кажется, мой способ достаточно безопасный и даже более удобный чем БД. К тому-же еще и быстрый.. А какие варианты кроме файла и БД есть? никаких. Хранить в txt или двоичных файлах не рекомендую(даже в зашифрованном виде).

Comment: Ну то понятно, просто подумал если проект развернуть для общественности, то думаю такие варианты там не прокатят. Ибо не для простолюдных эти движения. Там будет проще сделать поля ввода ключей и токенов в панели настроек плагина. Далее все просто. Ну пока что будет использовать внутри кода, и тестировать.

Comment: Я и говорю про поля ввода ключей и токенов в панели настроек, но пусть эти настройки хранятся как php-программа =)

Comment: Покажите пример, а то я не совсем наверно понял о чем вы говорите, если т.е вы хотите записывать данные в php файл ?

Comment: <?php $pattern = '<?php $vk_api_key="'.$_POST["vk_api_key"].'"; file_put_contents('keys.php', $pattern);

Comment: Ну я, конечно упрощенно. $_POST надо проверить и все такое да и шаблон может быть сложнее в отличии от того какие будут настройки. Потом файл keys.php подключайте через require_once и все работает.

Comment: Мысль понял, ну это не особо и защита, легче уже вшить это в файл. Но для общего пользования такое не подойдет, на разных серверах разные права и т д, т.е работа с базой стабильна, то в этом случае может быть крайне все не стабильно. А для себе-пользования тогда уже лушче вшить все апи и все.. как то так

Comment: Да не, эта штука стабильна как сама логика, но для себе-пользования со всем этим мучиться, конечно, нет смысла)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70569/discussion-between-webstackoverload-and--).